# Can permutations be solved by cases?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> "A Math Club has 12 members. They have to choose euclid contest team
>   of 3 members and a National Math Competition team with 4 members. Students can be on both teams, but James agrees to
>   only be on at most one team. In how many ways can both teams be chosen?"

Here's what I thought should be the answer but doesn't make much sense:

Case 1: James is in Euclid team:

$\therefore $  $11\choose2$ for Euclid Team

This would be because James is in team Euclid assumed so we only have to get 2 other players and we have 11 students left.

Also : $11\choose4$ for Math team

so total ways would be  $11\choose2$ . $11\choose4$ (Product Rule)

Case 2: James is in Math team:

$\therefore $  $11\choose3$ for Math team

This would be because james is in team Math assumed so we only have to get 3 other players and we have 11 students left.

Also : $11\choose3$ for Euclid team , as the 11 students can form a team of 3 for Euclid competition here.

so total ways would be  $11\choose3$ . $11\choose3$ (Product Rule)

Case 3: James in no team

$\therefore $  $11\choose3$ . $11\choose4$ (Product Rule)

as James is in no team so we are left with 11 people for both teams

Now the question is did I do it correctly? Because I have never seen cases being used in a permutation questions?

Therfore, The total number of ways would be to add all the cases meaning

Case 1 + Case 2 + Case 3 :

($11\choose2$ . $11\choose4$) + ($11\choose3$ . $11\choose3$) +($11\choose3$ . $11\choose4$)

Is that correct?

Comment: Please dont misuse/overuse the blockquote.

Comment: okay!! gotcha!!

Comment: Your problem is to count how many ways *both* teams can be chosen.  This is not a job for the Sum Rule.

Comment: You want the product rule in each of the three cases and then  the sum rule for the total number of ways to choose the teams. To see why, consider working a much smaller example and writing out all the teams.

Comment: @quasi how can it be $8\choose4$? I mean all the students except for James can be on both teams so why did we subtract 3 from 11??

Comment: Right, my mistake. Still, the cases are not sums.

Comment: @EthanBolker I see what you mean but, I am confused as to why product rule, becuase my teacher told me that product rule is used when you want to form 1 team from 2 different lists here we want to make 2 different teams from 1 list?

Comment: @quasi that's what I was confused with, isn't sum rule used when you have 2 different teams with 2 different lists and then add the possiblities. And product rule is used when we have 1 team but 2 different lists?

Comment: The product rule is used when you have sequential choices, and the number of choices at each stage only depends on which stage. Thus, for case (1), the first stage has $\binom{11}{2}$ choices, and after those choices are made, the second stage has $\binom{11}{4}$ choices. For _each_ of the $\binom{11}{2}$ choices for the first team, there are $\binom{11}{4}$ choices for the other team.

Comment: Since people (other than James) can be on both teams, you are essentially picking the two teams independently. I think you're better off thinking in terms of whether choices are independent or from different cases rather than learning rules for "sum rule" and "product rule". And do small examples. What if each team had just one member?

Comment: OHHHH! I see what you meann so basically if they are to be formed then we do product rule and when we have 2 different cases we add them?! it makes sense now, Thanks @quasi and EthanBolker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding the wish of James there are $\binom{12}4\binom{12}3$ possibilities.

Among them are $\binom{11}3\binom{11}2$ possibilies with James is in both teams.

Subtracting we find: $$\binom{12}4\binom{12}3-\binom{11}3\binom{11}2$$ possibilities that do not disregard the wish of James.

Comment: I am confused as to why you are considering $12\choose4$ and $12\choose3$ into consideration as john can be on atmost 1 team so if he is then you get the second case but the first case didn't make sense to me?? can you explain or so please?

Comment: There are $\binom{12}3$ possibilities to form the euclid contest team and $\binom{12}4$ the other team. That gives $\binom{12}4\times\binom{12}3$ possibilities to form both teams (not paying attention to James yet). Do you agree with that?

Comment: But we have 12 students including James so how can we take James as a person in both teams as if james is confirmed to be in one team then we cant form other teams without him right? 

OR do you mean that We do not pay attention to what james wants yet?

Comment: Right, but at firsthand we do not reckon with that wish. Afterwards we find out how many possibilities are not okay because James has been chosen twice. This number of possibilities is subtracted so that the number of possibilities with James chosen once or not at all remains. It appears that $\binom{11}3\binom{11}2$ possibilities must be subtracted (in these possibilities James is chosen twice).

Comment: I get what you mean now?! although would my method be wrong??

Comment: Your method is okay